# Get pipe utilization?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, named-pipes

**This is marked as answered, but if anybody knows an fstat-like system call that can achieve this, I'd love to hear about it.**

I'm working on some applications that communicate over a named pipe (required for legacy reasons). A pipe has a fixed capacity (65536 bytes is Linux default) and, when it gets full, blocks writes until sufficient space is available. This means a slower consumer will block a faster producer. What I'd like to be able to do is periodically monitor the pipe's utilization.

Is it possible to get a pipe's data size (size of data not yet read from the pipe)? fstat always returns 0 for size, expected behavior according to the man page.

Is there a posix compliant way of getting pipe capacity? Apparently, fcntl can do this since Linux 2.6.35. However, this needs to be able to run on earlier version of Linux.

Comment: are you trying to access these stats from an external process?

Comment: nope, the consumer process ideally.

Comment: why is the consumer slow? are you in a while(read) { process_data } type situation? I ask, because if that's the case you can asynchronously read data and push it into a consumer buffer by setting O_ASYNC flag on the consumer side of the fd

Comment: Agreed. That's the gist of the consumer's design. In this particular case, there's potentially thousands of producers, each writing less than or equal to PIPE_BUF, and one consumer. While I'm not too worried that the producers will becomes blocked, the disparity in numbers, process scheduling, and a variety of other factors make it a possibility. I'd like to monitor capacity "just in case" and alarm if needed. If nothing else, a software bug in the consumer could wreck havoc on the system. Now, for these reasons and more, a pipe isn't the optimal communication mechanism, but it's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the pipe in nonblocking mode on one or both ends and always attempt to read or write the full pipe buffer capacity.  `read`/`write` will then  most likely return less than that.

What a nonblocking `read` returns is how much was in the pipe at that time.
What a nonblocking `write` returns is how much space was left in the pipe.

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately, the legacy setup is one reader but multiple writers, each writer ensuring the message size is less than or equal to PIPE_BUF.

Comment: You don't need both. An unblocking reader is enough. If you can't modify your consumer, the unblocking reader can be just an intermediary that shovels bytes to another pipe for the actual reader.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is indeed a viable solution (for the first question anyways). Unfortunately, it's not ideal for the application in question - the code reading from the pipe is not the same code doing the monitoring of resources (think separation of concerns). However, I can work with this.